# Google Maps API -- Setting Icon for Marker Results in Error: "constructor Error cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create some markers to add using the Google Maps API, but if I try to specify an icon, I get the error: "constructor Error cannot be invoked without 'new'".

I'm running this via locahost.

**Things I have tried:**

- Creating the marker, then setting the icon afterwards.
- Different versions of the API.
- Plugging my API key into the JSFiddle. (No errors.)
- Removing/commenting out the icon lines. (Runs fine with the default icon.)

The code is pretty much verbatim from the Google-supplied JSFiddle for this, and it works there, but not on the page I'm working on.

```
const latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.location[0], this.location[1]);
this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 10
  },
  draggable: false
});
```

I should have a circle icon at the specified position, but instead I get the following:

> js?v=weekly&key=(APIKEY):53 Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Error cannot be invoked without 'new'
>       at new Yc (:53)
>       at Object._.$c (:53)
>       at :56
>       at :56
>       at :56
>       at _.nf.setIcon (:66)
>       at *.nf.*.T.setValues (:165)
>       at _.nf.mf [as constructor] (:79)
>       at new _.nf (:79)
>       at User.createMarker (classes.js:329)

It looks to me like there's a problem in the API's code that's making it difficult to debug the actual problem that's triggering the error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Does anything work on localhost? Maybe the API key is restricted to your production domain? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Yeah, everything else works fine. Like I mentioned above, if I just comment out the icon, it runs without any problems (but with the default icon, which I don't want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the API is calling on a global Error object within the setIcon chain of functions (despite, apparently, a total lack of errors), which was causing an error due to me having overridden it with a custom Error class I had naively tried to add to the project.

Info on Error:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Answer (score 0):

Did you place the place in a class? I changed the official JSFiddle to use a class and it works.

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -25.363882,
      lng: 131.044922
    }
  });

  var Location = class Location {
    constructor(lat, lng) {
      this.location = [lat, lng]
      const latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.location[0], this.location[1]);
      this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 10
        },
        draggable: false
      });
      this.marker.setMap(map);
    }

  }

  var location = new Location(-25.363882, 131.044922);

}
```

Comment: Yes, it’s part of a larger class.